# Poincaré quasi-isomorphism

Tags: homology, at.algebraic-topology, co.combinatorics

Suppose we have a simplicial combinatorial manifold (just a triangulated manifold) and its Poincaré dual cell complex. 
Corresponding homology simplicial and homology cell complexes are quasi-isomorphic of cause. But this quasi-isomormohism as it usually quoted from Solomon Lefschetz "Alg Topology" book is transcendental. Can we have a reasonable formula for such a quasi-isomorphism (for homology over a good field at least)?

Update
1) sorry for Russian math-slang use of "transcendental" here "transcendental"="non-constructive" 
2) among the others one motivation is to see really the Poincare duality for simplicial chains and cochains of the given triangulation of a manifold.

UUpdate
The problem has a nice very canonical solution, with Laplas operator Green function heat kerenel etc. It allows to solve some problems. The preprint(s) are in preparation.

Comment: Are you asking about the map of chain complexes whose domain is the simplicial homology chain complex and whose range is the chain complex for the cohomology of the dual polyhedral complex? I'm not sure what you don't like about the formula. 

Comment: I'm not getting the question either.  What is "transcendental" about this Poincare isomorphism?


Comment: I am asking about explicit formulas for two maps between simplicial homology chain complex and cell homology chain  of the dual polyhedral  complex forming quiasi-isomorphism 

Comment: To Greg -- may be misleading my use of "Poincare" in my question. Nothing transcnental in standard isomormphism of *homology* and *cohomology* complexes of dual. The isomorphism is transcendental betwin homology and homology of dual cell complex (or cohomology and cohomology of dual cell complex)  

Comment: I still do not understand what 'trascendental' is supposed to mean in this context...

Comment: It sounds like he is using "transcendental" to mean "non-canonical"?  I was thrown because there is no evident connection to transcendental numbers like $\pi$.


Comment: I imagined something more along the meaning with which Grothendieck writes (in a footnote to one of his *Dix Exposés*, if I recall correctly) that Chern classes of complex representations of a finite group are 'trascendent' (in his case, because the construction seemingly depends on the exponential map; it was proved later by Ove Kroll that in fact one can construct these Chern classes purely algebraically, though)

Comment: So it sounds like you're not interested in the Poincare duality map (homology - cohomology), but you're interested in the map between the two coodinate systems -- homology computed in the chain complex for simplicial homology vs. homology for the chain complex for the dual polyhedral homology. Is that correct?

Comment: Said another way, you have two CW-decompositions for the same space $X$, call the first decomposition $A$ and the 2nd $B$, and you want to find a cellular approximation for the identity map $Id : X \to X$ from $X$ with the $A$ CW-structure, to $X$ with the $B$ CW-structure, and compute the induced map on the corresponding chain complexes for homology? 

Comment: Yes Ryan, you are correct. Sorry for "transcendental" -- probably it comes from Russian use -- meaning "non constrctive" "no effective formula" in this context 

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't know a nice chain map of the type you're looking for.  I occasionally have need for this kind of thing when coding software but what I do is completely ad-hoc.  I'd love to know a "natural" such construction, myself.  But when you get down to it you really need to make some choices.  The barycenter of a simplex has to be sent to one of the vertices of the simplex -- which one do you choose?  etc, etc...

Comment: Yes Rian, For the nice chain map over integes there is no much hope. Over the field () you can take arithmetical mean of choices in the case of barycentric subdivision of simplex -- this gives a formulas. But when we come to baricentric subdivision of a ball complex which appears in dual complex to simplicial manifold this simple-minded choices became-non constructive and here I hope for some better science 

Comment: Dear Nikolai, maybe the geometric (and rather explicit) description of duality for intersection homology in Goresky and McPherson paper (in Topology, 1980) can be useful for your purposes?

Comment: Thanks Gil, I will try to look at and recall. I have a very strong feeling that there is a good and nice answer. 

Answer (score 4):

Both the cell complex, $C$, and the dual cell complex $C'$ are refined by the first barycentric subdivision $BC$. There are maps $C \to BC$ and $C' \to BC$, sending a cell $\sigma$ to the sum of all cells of the same dimension contained in $\sigma$; these maps are both quasi-isomorphisms.

So, if you allow me to formally invert quasi-isomorphisms, I'm done.

Is the question whether there is an honest map of chain complexes between $C$ and $C'$, without subdividing?

---

**UPDATE** Here is something you can do, and something you can't do.

With $C$ and $BC$ as above, and $r : C \to BC$ the refinement map, there is a homotopy inverse $s: BC \to C$. (More precisely, $C \to BC \to C$ is the identity, and $BC \to C \to BC$ is homotopic to the identity.) Working the same trick with $r' : C' \to BC$, we get quasi-isomorphisms between $C$ and $C'$ which are homotopy inverse to each other. As you will see, however, this construction is very nongeometric and inelegant.

Construction: Let $q:BC \to Q$ be the cokernel of $C \to BC$. An easy computation checks that each $Q_i$ is free. Since $C \to BC$ is a quasi-isomorphism, $Q$ is exact. An exact complex of free $\mathbb{Z}$ modules must be isomorphic to a direct sum of complexes of the form $\cdots \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0 \to \cdots$. Choose such a decomposition of $Q$, so $Q_i = A_{i+1} \oplus A_{i}$ and the map $Q_i \to Q_{i-1}$ is the projection onto $A_{i}$.

Now, consider the map $q_i^{-1}(A_i) \to A_i$ in degree $i$. This is surjective, and  $A_i$ is free, so choose a section $p^1_i$. We also define a map $p^2_i$ from the $A_{i+1}$ summand of $Q_{i}$ to $BC_i$ by $p^2_i = d p^1_{i+1} d^{-1}$. In this way, we get maps $p_i = p^1_i \oplus p^2_i: Q_{i} \to BC_i$ which give a map of chain complexes.

We note that $qp: Q \to Q$ is the identity. Therefore, $1-pq$, a map from $BC \to BC$, lands in the subcomplex $C$ and gives a section $s:BC \to C$. Proof of the claim about homotopies will be provided on request.

---

On the other hand, here is something you can't do: Get the quasi-isomorphism to respect the symmetries of your original space. For example, let $C$ be the chain complex of the cube, and $C'$ the chain complex of the octahedron. I claim that there is no quasi-isomorphism $C \to C'$ which commutes with the group $S_4$ of orientation preserving symmetries.

Consider what would happen in degree $0$. A vertex of the cube must be sent to some linear combination of the vertices of the octahedron. By symmetry, it must be set to 
$$a (\mbox{sum of the "near" vertices}) + b (\mbox{sum of the "far" vertices})$$
for some integers $a$ and $b$. But then the map on $H_0$ is multiplication by $3(a+b)$, and cannot be $1$.

---

I imagine you want something stronger then my first answer, but weaker than my second. I am not sure what it it, though.

Comment: Dear David, you got the point -- i need the explicit formula for the invertion of your chain maps to form a quasyi-isomorpism .  And this in general is transcnental for  BC->C' I hope very much that there should be a nice and scientific one.

Comment: Dear  David, yes your construction is of cause what one have in mind. While, I need a finite formula, this means that choices have to be fixed somehow respecting combinatorics. I hope that this can be done in a nice way. 

Answer (score 3):

If $c$ is the cochain that is equal to 1 on some (oriented) simplex $s$ and is zero elsewhere, then the dual of $c$ is the barycentric star of $s$ i.e. the union of the simplices of the barycentric subdivision of dimension equal to the codimension of $s$ and passing through the barycenter of $s$; we consider this as an element of the simplicial complex of the barycentric subdivision. The orientation of the barycentric star is determined by the orientations of $s$ and of the manifold.

Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry for my misleading use of "Poincare" in my question. That stays not for canonical Poincare duality between chains and cochains but for Poincare dual cell complex.  Nothing transcnental in standard isomormphism of homology and cohomology complexes of dual. The isomorphism is transcendental betwin homology and homology of dual cell complex (or cohomology and cohomology of dual cell complex)